# Assign grep count to variable

Tags: bash, shell, grep

How to assign the result of

```
grep -c "some text" /tmp/somePath
```

into variable so I can echo it.

```
#!/bin/bash
some_var = grep -c "some text" /tmp/somePath
echo "var value is: ${some_var}"
```

I also tried:

```
some_var = 'grep -c \"some text\" /tmp/somePath'
```

But I keep getting: `command not found`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To assign the output of a command, use `var=$(cmd)` (as [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically tells you if you paste your script there).

```
#!/bin/bash
some_var=$(grep -c "some text" /tmp/somePath)
echo "var value is: ${some_var}"
```

Comment: Thanks, for answer. But how to use input variable in executable part of code? my_var=$(grep "word" $1) - not works

Answer (score 36):

Found the issue

Its the assignment, this will work:

```
some_var=$(command)
```

While this won't work:

```
some_var = $(command)
```

Thank you for your help! I will accept first helpful answer.

Comment: Can't vote this up enough... These are the type of answers that make me grateful for SO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this insight. Agree with Charlie. Can't vote this up enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
some_var=$(grep -c "some text" /tmp/somePath)
```

From `man bash`:

```
   Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the com‐
   mand name.  There are two forms:

          $(command)
   or
          `command`

   Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the com‐
   mand substitution with the standard output of  the  command,  with  any
   trailing newlines deleted.
```

Comment: Variable assignments **cannot** have spaces around the `=`.

Comment: @michaelb958 You're right. My post was fixed before I noticed the problem.

Comment: Lev this was the problem :)