# grep command to check count of a string in If statement

Tags: shell

I am not sure what is wrong with this syntax

```
 if  [[ echo $list | grep -c 'test'  ]] > 0 ; then
   echo "hello"

 fi
```

this `echo $list | grep -c 'test'` prints 1
and I tried

```
 if  [[ echo $list | grep -c 'test' -gt 1 ]] ; then
   echo "hello"

 fi
```

Nothing worked. What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: maybe `if echo "$list"| grep -q 'test' ; then do_your_stuff ; fi` will meet your needs. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign grep count to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327355/assign-grep-count-to-variable)